# Python: code review for a function to clip a raster image with a polygon

Tags: python, performance, debugging, optimization, memory

I'm requesting a review of the following code. I have a spatial referenced image and a polygon. I wrote a code (see below) to clip this image in order to save a new image (clipped area). This function clip a raster based on the geometry of a feature class. Clipping based on the geometry means that you will use the boundaries of all the features in the feature class to clip the raster and not a minimum bounding rectangle of those features

Input: a polygon layer and one or more raster layers
Output: new raster layers, clipped to polygon boundaries

```
import osgeo.gdal
import shapefile
import struct, numpy, pylab
import numpy as np
import ogr
import osr,gdal
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import osgeo.gdal as gdal
import sys
from osgeo import gdal, gdalnumeric, ogr, osr
import Image,ImageDraw

def world2Pixel(geoMatrix, x, y):
    """
    Uses a gdal geomatrix (gdal.GetGeoTransform()) to calculate
    the pixel location of a geospatial coordinate
    (http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/clip-raster-using-shapefile.html)
    geoMatrix
    [0] = top left x (x Origin)
    [1] = w-e pixel resolution (pixel Width)
    [2] = rotation, 0 if image is "north up"
    [3] = top left y (y Origin)
    [4] = rotation, 0 if image is "north up"
    [5] = n-s pixel resolution (pixel Height)

    """
    ulX = geoMatrix[0]
    ulY = geoMatrix[3]
    xDist = geoMatrix[1]
    yDist = geoMatrix[5]
    rtnX = geoMatrix[2]
    rtnY = geoMatrix[4]
    pixel = np.round((x - ulX) / xDist).astype(np.int)
    line = np.round((ulY - y) / xDist).astype(np.int)
    return (pixel, line)

def Pixel2world(geoMatrix, x, y):
    ulX = geoMatrix[0]
    ulY = geoMatrix[3]
    xDist = geoMatrix[1]
    yDist = geoMatrix[5]
    coorX = (ulX + (x * xDist))
    coorY = (ulY + (y * yDist))
    return (coorX, coorY)

def RASTERClipByPolygon(inFile,poly,outFile):
    # Open the image as a read only image
    ds = osgeo.gdal.Open(inFile,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    # Check the ds (=dataset) has been successfully open
    # otherwise exit the script with an error message.
    if ds is None:
        raise SystemExit("The raster could not openned")
    # Get image georeferencing information.
    geoMatrix = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    ulX = geoMatrix[0]
    ulY = geoMatrix[3]
    xDist = geoMatrix[1]
    yDist = geoMatrix[5]
    rtnX = geoMatrix[2]
    rtnY = geoMatrix[4]
    # get the WKT (= Well-known text)
    dsWKT = ds.GetProjectionRef()
    # get driver information
    DriverName = ds.GetDriver().ShortName
    # open shapefile (= border of are of interest)
    shp = osgeo.ogr.Open(poly)
    if len(shp.GetLayer()) != 1:
         raise SystemExit('The shapefile must have exactly one layer')
    # Create an OGR layer from a boundary shapefile
    layer = shp.GetLayer(0)
    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    # Make sure that it is a polygon
    if geometry.GetGeometryType() != osgeo.ogr.wkbPolygon:
            raise SystemExit('This module can only load polygon')
    # get Extent of the clip area
    X_min, X_max, Y_min, Y_max = layer.GetExtent()
    # Convert the layer extent to image pixel coordinates
    uldX, uldY = world2Pixel(geoMatrix, X_min, Y_max)
    lrdX, lrdY = world2Pixel(geoMatrix, X_max, Y_min)
    # Calculate the pixel size of the new image
    pxWidth = int(lrdX - uldX)
    pxHeight = int(lrdY - uldY)
    # get the Coodinate of left-up vertex of the pixel
    X_minPixel, Y_maxPixel = Pixel2world(geoMatrix, uldX, uldY)
    # get polygon's vertices
    pts = geometry.GetGeometryRef(0)
    points = []
    for p in range(pts.GetPointCount()):
        points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
    pnts = np.array(points).transpose()
    # work band by band
    nBands = ds.RasterCount
    # panchromatic
    if nBands == 1:
        band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        # get nodata value
        nodata = band.GetNoDataValue()
        # convert band in Array
        bandArray = band.ReadAsArray()
        del band
        # clip arrey
        bandArray_Area = bandArray[uldY:lrdY, uldX:lrdX]
        del bandArray
        # Create 2D Polygon Mask. Mode 'L', not '1', because
        # Numpy-1.5.0 / PIL-1.1.7 does not support the numpy.array(img)
        # conversion nicely for bivalue images.
        img = Image.new('L', (pxWidth, pxHeight), 0)
        target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName(DriverName).Create(outFile, pxWidth, pxHeight, nBands, ds.GetRasterBand(1).DataType)
        target_ds.SetGeoTransform((X_minPixel, xDist, rtnX,Y_maxPixel, rtnY, yDist))
        pixels, line = world2Pixel(target_ds.GetGeoTransform(),pnts[0],pnts[1])
        listdata = [(pixels[i],line[i]) for i in xrange(len(pixels))]
        ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(listdata, outline=1, fill=1)
        mask = numpy.array(img)
        bandArray_Masked = bandArray_Area*mask
        del bandArray_Area, mask
        target_ds.GetRasterBand(nBands).WriteArray(bandArray_Masked)
        target_ds.GetRasterBand(nBands).SetNoDataValue(nodata)
    else:
        img = Image.new('L', (pxWidth, pxHeight), 0)
        target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName(DriverName).Create(outFile, pxWidth, pxHeight, nBands, ds.GetRasterBand(1).DataType)
        target_ds.SetGeoTransform((X_min, xDist, rtnX,Y_max, rtnY, yDist))
        pixels, line = world2Pixel(target_ds.GetGeoTransform(),pnts[0],pnts[1])
        listdata = [(pixels[i],line[i]) for i in xrange(len(pixels))]
        ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(listdata, outline=1, fill=1)
        mask = numpy.array(img)
        for bandno in range(1, nBands+1):
            band = ds.GetRasterBand(bandno)
            nodata = band.GetNoDataValue()
            # convert band in Array
            bandArray = band.ReadAsArray()
            del band
            # clip arrey
            bandArray_Area = bandArray[ulY:lrY, ulX:lrX]
            del bandArray
            bandArray_Masked = bandArray_Area*mask
            target_ds.GetRasterBand(bandno).WriteArray(bandArray_Masked)
            del bandArray_Area
            target_ds.GetRasterBand(bandno).SetNoDataValue(nodata)
    # set the reference info
    if len(dsWKT) is 0:
        # Source has no projection (needs GDAL >= 1.7.0 to work)
        target_ds.SetProjection('LOCAL_CS["arbitrary"]')
    else:
    # Make the target raster have the same projection as the source
        target_ds.SetProjection(dsWKT)
    target_ds = None
```

Comment: Can't you just round (or truncate) the vertex coordinates so they lie on a pixel boundary and then figure out how much this moves it?

Comment: @martineau. i find this solution. See the code to see the solution 
# get the Coodinate of left-up vertex of the pixel: 

X_minPixel, Y_maxPixel = Pixel2world(geoMatrix, uldX, uldY)

Comment: Do you use the difference between `lrdX, lrdY` and `X_minPixel, Y_maxPixel` to translate the polygon vertices?

Comment: @martineau with "Pixel2world" i determine the geographic coordinate (x,y) of the left-up vertex of the pixel-i (where the left-up boundary box of the polygon drop). After, with these parameters (x,y) i set the create a new image in gdal using the line target_ds.SetGeoTransform((X_minPixel, xDist, rtnX,Y_maxPixel, rtnY, yDist))

Comment: Using the `xDist` & `yDist` from the `geoMatrix` is not what I'm talking about. What I mean is round the polygon vertex so it lies on a pixel boundary, transform that back to world coords, and finally compute the deltaX & deltaY difference between the two coordinates. This will be in world coordinates and should then be used to translate the coordinates of all the polygon's vertices forcing it to be aligned the way you want.

Comment: @martineau, thanks for your suggestion. I am honest to say that i cannot figure how round the polygon vertex to lie on a pixel boundary.

Comment: Well, pixel boundaries are usually integers. It might be helpful to image what the coordinates of two adjacent pixels would be and then determine how an arbitrary non-integer coordinate would have to be manipulated to be forced to be at the nearest pixel location.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done easily in R. I just realized that the question is specific for python. Therefore I made the edit. there are wrappers available to run R within python or python within R, please check package rpy2 .

```
#Load library
library(raster)

## Read the shapefile
myshp <- shapefile("shapefile.shp")


## Reading the raster you want to crop
myraster <- raster('image.tif')


## create a layer only for the shape, the parameter inverse = TRUE or FALSE is imp
new_raster = mask(myraster, myshp, filename = "newras.tif", inverse = FALSE)
```